# sqlite3_exec returns 26 in linux

Tags: database, encryption, sqlite, sqlcipher

i am writing an application which encrypt the SQLITE3 database. for encryption i have used SQLCIPHER.i am able to perform encryption and decryption of Database from command line.i am writing the client app using c++. here is my code to test the key (used for encryption).

```
int main()
{
    sqlite3 *DataBase;

    if(sqlite3_open("encrypted.db", &DataBase)== SQLITE_OK)
    {

        int result = sqlite3_exec(DataBase, "PRAGMA KEY = 'testkey';", NULL, NULL, NULL); 

        result = sqlite3_exec(DataBase,"SELECT user_id FROM USER;", NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if(result == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            cout<<"sqlite3_exec success"<<endl;
        }        
        else 
        {
                    cout<<"sqlite3_exec failed"<<endl;
                    cout<<"sqlite3_exec returns "<<result<<endl;

            }       

    }
}
```

i am able to the same using command line:

```
./sqlite3 encrypted.db
PRAGMA key = 'testkey';
SELECT user_id FROM USER;
```

i have encrypted my access.db using:

```
./sqlite3 access.db 
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'encrypted.db' AS encrypted KEY 'testkey'; 
sqlite> SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted'); 
sqlite> DETACH DATABASE encrypted;
```

i dont get why i am able to do the same using command line and not by c++ code. please let me know if i am doing something wrong.

please also let me know if i have to access the encrypted database then i should first decrypt it and then i should read the plaintext database, are there no API's which i could use directly to read encrypted database?

any help is appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i am able to do it. while executing my program i need to include -lsqlciper also. adding that successfully executed the code. 
i build it using 
"**g++ testSQLCipher.cpp -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -lsqlcipher -L /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -ldl -o testSQL**"

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to issue a [`PRAGMA key`](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#key) command, you must quote the passphrase value in your C++ application.  Reviewing the sample you submitted, you have not done this.  Alternatively, you could just call [`sqlite3_key`](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#sqlite3_key).

Comment: Nick, thanks for your reply. while posting here i by mistake did not add quote. in my code i am using quotes. i had first installed sqlite3,  i used all these apis worked fine. after that i installed sqlcipher and here thet pain starts. i don't get why i am not able to execute sqlite3 commands programmatically. has it to do anything with  installation or installation order or package version, linking of binaries?

Comment: i forgot to mention that when i first used sqlite3_key but i was gettiing error "'sqlite3_key' was not declared in the scope" so i switch to sqlite_exec using PRAGMA.

Comment: That may be an issue with the integration of SQLCipher within your application.  To make `sqlite3_key` available you must include `SQLITE_HAS_CODEC` within your CFLAGS.

Comment: while configuring and in my c++ program both places i have added SQLITE_HAS_CODEC but did not work. i think there is some problem with linking. anyway i will try to explore and will keep you posted.